# Can I Download & Use Microsoft Edge in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How can i download and use **Microsoft Edge** in **Windows 8.1** ?

Comment: This is marked closed, but comes up on the top of Google search. Everyone below says it can't be done, but none of them bothered to point out that you can run Windows 10 in a pre-configured VM.  The options include Hyper-V, Virtualbox and VMWare. You can run these virtual machines on Windows, Mac or Linux. Go here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ and select the bottom VM, “Microsoft Edge on Win10”

Comment: Very recently MS has released a chromium-based Edge browser that does work on Win7 and Win8.1 
 The developer version is supposed to be good enough to use
 https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No. you can't.**

Microsoft Edge is not a standalone browser (as of now). I've also tried many a times for some alternative but no..

I've tried finding the setup file of this browser from the Windows 10 installed OS but couldn't.

ps. In future it might be available.

For more info, you can join [this conversation on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Can-I-download-Microsoft-Edge-for-my-Windows-8-1-laptop)

Comment: I don't know why do you think that it might be backported to other versions of Windows, but that won't happen. Their response is that you should upgrade to WIndows 10.

Comment: Oddly enough Edge is kind of a downgrade as it glitches in ways IE hasn't in new versions. :(

Comment: Microsoft has pulled anoter IE6 on us... by abandoning the IE ship and offering Edge only on Windows 10 they virtually guarantee we will be stuck with IE 11 for years to come.  We should create another upgrade your browser campaign.

Comment: Very recently, MS has a chromium-based Edge browser that does work on Win7 and Win8.1 
 The developer version is supposed to be good enough. 
 https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/

Answer (score 7):

A standalone version is not available. And Microsoft has no plans of releasing the edge browser on other versions of Windows besides 10 or any other platforms for that matter.
So to answer your question, **you can't**.

You can use a virtual machine if you want to use Edge on Windows.

You can read about this **[here](https://www.itechtics.com/download-win10-vm-edge-browser/)**.

Comment: Very recently MS released a chromium-based Edge browser that does work on Win7, Win8.1 
 The developer version is supposed to be good enough
 https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/